# Array state being empty inside useCallback but normally updated in components and useEffect

Tags: reactjs

I have an state of array which is mapped and a component renders for each object inside this array state. I also have a function callback that should, for now, console log this array state when i press Enter. The components is rendered and updated normally in every change of this array state, but the callback function logs an empty array every time. This useCallback has an array of dependencies with the state array inside. What am I missing??

The useEffect also logs the correct array state, the same that is being rendered by the components. Only the callback function is not. With the same array of dependencies

```
const [planners, setPlanners] = useState([])
const [workers, setWorkers] = useState([])

const onKeyPress = useCallback((event) => {
    if (event.key == 'Enter') {
        console.log(workers, planners)
    }
}, [workers, planners])

useEffect(() => {
    console.log('*')
    console.log(workers)
    console.log(planners)
    console.log('*')
}, [workers, planners])
```

Comment: How do you add items to these states?

Comment: I recommend you to call the onKeyPress directly in the function that is called when this key is pressed to prevent side effects.

Comment: @Konrad setPlanners([...planners, newObject]) when another component is clicked

Comment: i've put it in a fiddle here. Seems to work as expected: https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-fiddle-forked-joumni

Comment: @lmasneri sorry, I didn't understand. That onKeyPress is the new function i'm declaring and am calling with

useEffect(() => {
        document.addEventListener("keydown", onKeyPress, false)
    
        return () => {
          document.removeEventListener("keydown", onKeyPress, false)
        }
    }, [])

Comment: @Nsevens I found that my dependency array was empty on that useEffect for adding the event listener. Added the states to it and worked. With the function worked too. Is it better it pass the function or the two states to that dependecy array? Or does no matter? But thanks!

Comment: In this case it's the function that is the actual dependency. I'd update it to that, since in the future this function might change due to another condition (e.g changing dependencies of useCallback).

Answer (score 0):

If anyone happens to get stuck like I did:

I was calling the onKeyPress callback function this way:

```
useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("keydown", onKeyPress, false)

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("keydown", onKeyPress, false)
    }
}, [])
```

the dependency array was empty. Changing it to [onKeyPress] updated the state values inside the function

```
useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("keydown", onKeyPress, false)

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("keydown", onKeyPress, false)
    }
}, [onKeyPress])
```

Comment: Actually, it's `onKeyPress` which is the dependency. This is however correlated to `[workers, planners]`, resulting in the same in the end.